# jQuery - Change div color for even with selector :eq()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have **4 divs** with **same class name** and **select option** in each of them. How can I change background in ONLY **even divs** (2,4,6,8 etc) for select options?

I have tried with `:nth-child(even)`, with no luck and when I tried with `$(".tmgrpslc(1)").addClass('red');` It did changed the background of second select opetion and was correct. But as said I want to change background for **even select options**.

@Here is my code:*

```
<!-- First div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- second div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Third div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Fourth div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

If :eq is not good idea and there is other selectors that does the job, I am open to it.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSS solution. Use the psuedo selector `:nth-child(even)`

```css
div.col-md-6:nth-child(even) .tmgrpslc {
  background-color: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<!-- First div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- second div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Third div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Fourth div -->
<div class="col-md-6 selectgroups">
  <div class="nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="integer optional" for="choice_group">Choice group</label>
      <select class="tmgrpslc" name="[1460553694556][choice_group]" id="1460553694556_choice_group">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pugazh There is other col-md-6 divs inside the view/template. And as you can see, I tried to change background for `tmgrpslc` How can I change the select opetion with class `tmgrpslc` and not whole col-md-6 div.

Comment: Please refer updated answer. Are you referring to something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ":nth-child(even)" selector:

```
$(".selectgroups:nth-child(even)").css("background","#FFFFFF")
```

Comment: Tnx, How can I select the even select options not the div itself.

Comment: Adding the select's class to selector:  
`$(".selectgroups:nth-child(even) .tmgrpslc").css("background-color","black");`  
or with select element :  
`$(".selectgroups:nth-child(even) select").css("background-color","black");`